# Jest testing service call responses witth promises, useEffect and useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm having some difficulty testing this useEffect in jest. The following piece of code is within a react functional component and I want to return some mock values when the `serviceFn` is called. The returned data is written back to state.

```
//from service-factory.js
const serviceFn = () => (
  ({ personId }) => (
    ionXHR.request(
      `/persons/${personId}/`,
      'GET',
      null,
      'json',
    )
  )
);

//from Component.jsx
const service = useRef(serviceFn());
  useEffect(() => {
    
    service.current({ personId:123456 }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        setData(response.data);
        setLoadingState('SUCCESS');
      } else {
        setLoadingState('FAILED');
      }
    });
  }, [personId]);
```

I have the following, but not sure what else I would need.

```
function mockReturnFn() { return 'Test'; }
const wrapper = mount(<Component/>);
const somethingSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper, 'serviceFn').mockImplementation(mockReturnFn);
```

**Update:**

So, I think I'm getting close.

In my test file I had to import the function

```
import { serviceFn } from './service-factory';
jest.mock('./service-factory', () => ({ serviceFn : jest.fn() }));
```

In my test I have

```
serviceFn.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('test1234'));
```

The issue now with this is I am getting `service.current is not a function`

I tried to do this but now getting `_serviceFactory.serviceFn.mockImplementation is not a function`

```
jest.mock('./service-factory', () => (
  {
    serviceFn: {
      current: jest.fn(),
    },

  }
));
```

Comment: Where does serviceFn come from? You can't spy on it for functional components as you did. Please, don't truncate relevant parts.

Comment: I've added the serviceFn function above, it uses a library but it basically does a get request and returns a json object. I want to mock the returned value. Let me know if more info is required?

Answer (score 0):

`serviceFn` is factory function, it returns a function that makes requests.

Considering it's named export, it should be initially stubbed as:

```
jest.mock('./service-factory', () => {
  const mockService = jest.fn();
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    mockService,
    serviceFn: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockService)
  }
});
```

`mockService` is exposed and allows to mock specific responses:

```
mockService.mockResolvedValue({ data: ... });
```

Since it's basic wrapper over `ionXHR`, it's also possible to mock responses one level higher on `ionXHR.request` calls.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm stilling getting the same issue. ```service.current is not a function```, how would I get around this ?

Comment: In the code I posted, it's supposed to be a function, this error is impossible because `typeof serviceFn() === 'function'`. Make sure you pasted it as is AND there's no `serviceFn.mockImplementation(...)`, it will ruin the mock. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce it.